# How to to create a key/value map from a string in java (more complicated)

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have a text like

`"SimpleKey1: word1. SimpleKey2Word1 SimpleKey2Word2: word word word, word word. word word. CompoundKey3 / CompoundKey3: word word word, word. Key3: word. CompoundKey4Word1 CompoundKey4Word2 / CompoundKey4Word3 CompoundKey4Word4: word words, words word-word (word 18 word 100 ).  CompoundKey5 / CompoundKey5: word word."`

I need to parse that string in order obtain a key/value map like:

```
SimpleKey1: word1. 
SimpleKey2Word1 SimpleKey2Word2: word word word, word word. word word. 
CompoundKey3 / CompoundKey3: word word word, word. 
CompoundKey4Word1 CompoundKey4Word2 / CompoundKey4Word3 CompoundKey4Word4: word words,    words word-word (word 18 word 100 ).  
CompoundKey5 / CompoundKey5: word word.
```

Note that the key can contains slash character (/) and the values can contain special characters.

I can't figure out what regular expression I should to use.

Thanks.

Comment: What marks the end of a list of values for a given key?

Comment: @m0skit0 - It seems each value ends with the last period and space before a valid key (letters, numbers, spaces, and slashes).

Comment: Are we supposed to guess at the specification from your example, or can you provide the specification?

Answer (score 4):

```
String data = "SimpleKey1: word1. SimpleKey2Word1 SimpleKey2Word2: word "
            + "word word, word word. word word. CompoundKey3 / CompoundKey3: "
            + "word word word, word. Key3: word. CompoundKey4Word1 "
            + "CompoundKey4Word2 / CompoundKey4Word3 CompoundKey4Word4: word "
            + "words, words word-word (word 18 word 100 ). CompoundKey5 / "
            + "CompoundKey5: word word.";
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("([\\w\\s/]+):(.*?)(?=$|([\\w\\s/]+):)");
Matcher m=p.matcher(data);
while(m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group().trim());
```

output:

```
SimpleKey1: word1.
SimpleKey2Word1 SimpleKey2Word2: word word word, word word. word word.
CompoundKey3 / CompoundKey3: word word word, word.
Key3: word.
CompoundKey4Word1 CompoundKey4Word2 / CompoundKey4Word3 CompoundKey4Word4: word words, words word-word (word 18 word 100 ).
CompoundKey5 / CompoundKey5: word word.
```

If you want to get key use `m.group(1)`. For value you can use `m.group(2)` like

```
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println("key=>"+m.group(1));
    System.out.println("value=>"+m.group(2));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex `(.+?)(?=\.\s*(([A-Z])|($)))`